# Make AJAX get request to NOAA Rest API

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, api

I am trying to use NOAA's climate data API with AJAX https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2#gettingStarted and am not having any luck.  I get "bad request" when I try the AJAX way, and a CORS error when I try xhttp.  Does anyone know how to format a code snippet that would get a response, without any CORS issues?

Thanks!

Comment: did you follow the steps, do you have a token?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var noaaUrl = "https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/datasets";
var tokenFromNoaa = "aToken";

$.ajax({
    url: noaaUrl,
    headers:{
        token: tokenFromNoaa
    },
    success: function(returnedData) {
        console.log(returnedData);
    }
})
```

You need to replace the `"aToken"` with the actual token they gave you and replace `datasets` with whichever endpoint you want to access.

This should log the data into your browser console. You can access that by pressing F12. This code snippet also requires jQuery to use.